# While exporting data to excel from telerik RadGrid column value replaces with zeros

Tags: c#, excel, telerik

I am using telerik RadGrid in which i am showing data like one column contain CARDNUMBERS like

```
1234567894560900024

1234567894560900125
```

when i export this grid to excel the last three characters get replaced with zeros as shown below.

```
1234567894560900000

1234567894560900000
```

In the code behind data assigning code in shown below:

```
var cardNumber = gridRow.GetDataKeyValue("CARDNUMBER").ToString();

var lblCardNumber = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblCardNumber");

lblCardNumber.Text = cardNumber ;
```

where CARDNUMBER is database column name.

Comment: hint: what is datatype of column....?

Comment: In the database it has varchar datatype.

Comment: and the column in grid?

Comment: <ItemTemplate>
                                                                <asp:Label ID="lblCardNumber" runat="server" />
                                                            </ItemTemplate>

Comment: as i am using label and on data-bound i am giving text this label.

Comment: i have mentioned datatype string like <telerik:GridTemplateColumn DataType="System.String"  but still facing the same problem